# What statistics can compare dataset with shared values from same data source?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, anova

I have a dataset structured as follows:

[image]

I have split the data depending on the `Structure` column containing either "A", "B" or both as below:

[image]

In this dataset, if the `Structure` column contains "A", the observed value is copied in column `Contains A`. Similarly if the `Structure` column contains "B", the value is copied in column `Contains B` and if the `Structure` column contains both "A" and "B" then the value is copied in the column `Contains A & B`.

**Question:** What statistics parameter/analysis can you use to compare these three groups of data (`Contains A`, `Contains B`, `Contains A & B`) where some points are shared (and hence not independent) to show if there is any difference between these? Is there any test like a t-test or ANOVA which can be used to compare these three despite them sharing data points?

Comment: Please. Can anyone help?

Comment: I just want to say that any answer at any time (even few months to years down the road) would be appreciated for this question, as this is a persistent issue in my datasets.

Comment: Try posting on [Stats Stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com), you are more likely to get a response to this sort of question there.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there was a separate stats stackexchange.